# How to calculate relativeDuration in animateKeyframes

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to understand how to use `UIView.animateKeyframes` however I cannot for the life of me understand how to calculate the timings / durations.

I am trying to achieve the following:
I expect this entire animation to last 10 seconds, made up of...

> first addKeyframe runs at 01 seconds and takes 1 second
>
> second addKeyframe runs at 02 seconds and takes 1 second
>
> third addKeyframe runs at 05 seconds and takes 2 seconds
>
> fourth addKeyframe runs at 07 seconds and takes 1 second
>
> fourth addKeyframe runs at 09 seconds and takes 1 second

```
  fileprivate func animateWelcomeText() -> Void {

        let duration: TimeInterval = 10

        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: .calculationModeLinear, animations: {
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 1.0, relativeDuration: 1.0, animations: {
                self.introTextLabel.alpha = 1
            })

            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 2.0, relativeDuration: 1.0, animations: {
                self.introTextLabelTwo.alpha = 1
            })

            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 5.0, relativeDuration: 2.0, animations: {
                self.introTextLabel.alpha = 0
                self.introTextLabelTwo.alpha = 0
            })

            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 7.0, relativeDuration: 1.0, animations: {
                self.introTextLabelThree.alpha = 1
            })

            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 9.0, relativeDuration: 1.0, animations: {
                self.introTextLabelFour.alpha = 1
            })

        }) { (_) in
            print("Complete")
        }
    }
```

Nothing happens and then the animation completes and the last 2 items suddenly appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just math. Just divide all the values by your duration to get the relative values.

```
fileprivate func animateWelcomeText() -> Void {

    let duration: TimeInterval = 10

    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: .calculationModeLinear, animations: {
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 1/duration, relativeDuration: 1/duration, animations: {
            self.introTextLabel.alpha = 1
        })
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 2/duration, relativeDuration: 1/duration, animations: {
            self.introTextLabelTwo.alpha = 1
        })
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 5/duration, relativeDuration: 2/duration, animations: {
            self.introTextLabel.alpha = 0
            self.introTextLabelTwo.alpha = 0
        })

        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 7/duration, relativeDuration: 1/duration, animations: {
            self.introTextLabelThree.alpha = 1
        })

        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 9/duration, relativeDuration: 1/duration, animations: {
            self.introTextLabelFour.alpha = 1
        })

    }) { (_) in
        print("Complete")
    }
}
```

You have your values out of x (10). The method needs it out of 1.

Comment: Ah I see! I did not realise I needed to divide by duration. Thank you.

Comment: What you have is out of 10. What they want is out of 1.